# How do I open an obj file?

Tags: modeling, mesh, obj

I tried to open an .obj file using import but all I got was the workstation with the block. Yes, I'm a total beginner.

Comment: If you do your import and then look in the Outliner (topmost item in the rightmost column, by default, IIRC), what items do you see listed?  You should probably see a scene, renderlayers, world, camera, cube, and lamp -- if you see another entry then it's possible your OBJ imported correctly but isn't visible (e.g. it's really far away, very tiny, etc)

Comment: @AC pretty sure you can post this as an answer as it happens a lot because of the scale difference between the source and blender's workspace

Answer (score 14):

Only `.blend` files can be opened by Blender. Other file formats can be only imported.

[Obj Import](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/io_obj.html#obj)

Go to *File ‣ Import ‣ Wavefront (.obj)* and choose the file.

Remember to save the Blender file as a .blend file. If you wish to export the **obj** file go to the menu item *File ‣ Export ‣ Wavefront (.obj)*.

Answer (score 0):

*File > Import* , select the file you want to import but don't click *Ok*

On the right menu, before you import there is a list of options, choose a number , don't leave it at 0.0.,m then clik *Ok*. A black square will show click  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.