# Open a supported 3d object file type

Tags: scripting, import, blend-files

Complete re-edit of the question to make it less broad.  How do you make a script when executing at blender start-up not throw any errors about scene context

AttributeError: '_RestrictedContext'

This script works when run from a blend file.
The script imports a none blend file object

Simple?

Comment: Hi Nathan, Welcome to Blender.SE. I have edited your question and removed redundant information. I think it could be clearer in this shorter edit. Does it still conform to your original intent?

Comment: Hi Leander the edit is fine

Comment: How long does it take to get a reply usually??

Comment: Infinitely long, if no one knows the answer. [Some things](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/124320/30849) just may not be possible.

Comment: Thank you for that Leander, but if you recall what my question previously said, I have been searching.  I don't stop because the poor understanding of computers.  I'm looking for a way. . . Think of it as creating a temporary scene which then imports the file you want.  Key point you don't have click anything but the file you want

Comment: You can always modify the source code and compile it yourself. I thought about using the `load_post` [handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handler#module-bpy.app.handlers) to check for the filename extension, but it doesn't get fired when the filetype is unknown.

Comment: Well I previously tried by opening a blend file with a script in it that checks for extra argument, which it reads but when it tries to import that extra file it just doesn't, it will not import.  Pity people at blender never thought of making this work for users.  There used base would become even greater in no time

Comment: I tried my temporary file method again and it worked, but it still shows an error, file format is not supported in file "...". Then it says it's going to save to file.obj

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried, and the specific error. Other may be able to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: Leander, I could but it's neither a fix a problem really, no actual progress is being, it's still really messy I would expect solution not to need a temporary file, it should integrate into blender, better.

Comment: I think I've found a cleaner work around which involves saving the temp file as a startup file.  Any ideas to make it much easier?  I'm just really surprised that NO ONE has made this as an add-on, or even integrated it into blender, so the end user doesn't need to set it up for himself?

Comment: There are a number of questions / answers  re how to import from Y and export to Z  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17817/how-do-i-batch-import-one-format-then-export-to-another  On question edit, re restricted context https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/accessing-bpy-context-gives-a-restrictcontext-warning-how-to-fix-this

Comment: I'm sorry batFINGER although the error messages match not the same thing I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to get an add-on or some simple method for blender to open 3D files simply, so you can quickly view your 3d objects

Comment: See link above. Set up a script to  build a command line call with the appropriate import script   So eg `blender foo.obj` is `/pathtorealblender/blender foo.blend -P import_obj.py` (blender only works with blend files, you cannot open another format with it) Your latest edit. without any "_this / the script_" mentions your intention in title. however whatever you are trying to achieve if you get a restricted context or restricted data error then the answer matches perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing bpy.context gives a '\_RestrictContext' warning, how to fix this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/accessing-bpy-context-gives-a-restrictcontext-warning-how-to-fix-this)